# Navigation Drawer replace fragment with another problematically retaining the drawer option

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a basic app, containing a drawer layout. Each option in the drawer opens up a new fragment page for the user to view. Here is the drawer layout code.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the app_bar_main.xml code.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashBoardActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the content_main.xml. And also the main activity DashBoardActivity.kt

```
class DashBoardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_company_emissions, R.id.nav_your_emissions, R.id.nav_contact,
                R.id.nav_privacy_policy
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

From my understanding when you click a button in the drawer layout the fragment in the host fragment is replaced with the relevant clicked on fragment.

My questions is... How do I programatically put another fragment in this nav host view which hasn't been set up with the drawer layout. My problem is one of the fragments contains a profile for a user with an edit button. I want to open a new fragment when the edit button is clicked and wish for the user to still have access to the drawer when they do so don't want to go to another activity.

In my mind I just want to replace the profile_fragment with the edit_fragment. But when I've tried something like this below its placed the fragment onto of the profile one so that you have this weird looking screen with two fragments on top of one another.

```
val frag: Fragment = EditYourEmissionsFragment()
val fragMan:FragmentManager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
val fragTran: FragmentTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction()
fragTran.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, frag)
fragTran.addToBackStack(null)
fragTran.commit()
```

I'm still a relative novice when it comes to Android and Kotlin so am struggling to understand how I would go about doing my user case.

Scenario for trying to help paint a picture of what I want to happen:

1. User loads app and lands on home_fragment.
2. Opens drawer menu, clicks profile_fragment.
3. Once in profile_fragment opens the user presses edit.
4. A new fragment takes over the screen, but retains the ability to open the menu drawer.
5. User can now either open the drawer menu and navigate to other places across the app. Or save their profile and get taken back to the profile_fragment.

Thank you in advance for any help. Apologies if its not particularly clear.

Comment: You can host a fragment inside the current fragment by using childFragmentManager. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include the EditYourEmissionsFragment in the navigationGraph like this:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/EditYourEmissionsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.application.EditYourEmissionsFragment"
        android:label="Edit Profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_omissions"/>
```

and then on your ProfileFragment set the onClick to open the destination like this;

```
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        navController.navigate(R.id.EditYourEmissionsFragment)
```

and in your MainActivity

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host)
        return navController.navigateUp(myAppBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Evans, I have tried this method. It works to a degree, as does navigate to the edit page. However, the phones back button just refreshes the widget rather than going back to the profile fragment. So not sure how to fix this bit.

Comment: on the MainActivity add the override `onBackPressed` function

Comment: and put what inside it? As just adding that method doesn't change anything